# Importing doc file in wikimedia

Tags: docx, wiki, wikimedia

We have a large amount of documentation in word file format.
We are moving to a wikimedia platform for that documentation.

I'm looking to import all those doc files into our wiki. Is there a way to automate it?

Answer (score 0):

To help anyone that might come later on: 
I solved our issue with a combination of pandoc (convert docx file into zip files containing both images and html files) and html2wiki, to import those zip files.